# Amazon ECS LogConfiguration returns "unsupported property logConfiguration"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to get the LogConfiguration going for a specific task definition. But CloudFormation keeps complaining that it `Encountered unsupported property logConfiguration`

According to the documentation is should be able to use it.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_storage

```
"ContainerDefinitions" : [
  {
    "Name": "foo",
    "PortMappings": [ ... code omitted ... ],
    "logConfiguration" : {
      "logDriver" : "fluentd",
      "options" :  {
        "fluentd-address" : "foo:24224",
        "tag" : "foobar"
      }
    },
  }
]
```

Any clue what I am missing?

Comment: Have you specified the --log-driver option at the startup of docker daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at Amazon ECS documentation instead of AWS CloudFormation documentation.

According to CloudFormation [Amazon EC2 Container Service TaskDefinition ContainerDefinitions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html) **logConfiguration**
is not part of **ContainerDefinitions**

```
{
  "Command" : [ String, ... ],
  "Cpu" : Integer,
  "EntryPoint" : [ String, ... ],
  "Environment" : [ Environment Variable, ... ],
  "Essential" : Boolean,
  "Image" : String,
  "Links" : [ String, ... ],
  "Memory" : Integer,
  "MountPoints" : [ Mount Point, ... ],
  "Name" : String,
  "PortMappings" : [ Port Map, ... ],
  "VolumesFrom" : [ Volume From, ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if `LogConfiguration` wasn't available in CloudFormation at the time this question was asked, but it is now.

It is also case sensitive, so you'll need to change `logConfiguration` to `LogConfiguration`, `logDriver` to `LogDriver` and `options` to `Options`. Like so:

```
"ContainerDefinitions" : [
  {
    "Name": "foo",
    "PortMappings": [ ... code omitted ... ],
    "LogConfiguration" : {
      "LogDriver" : "fluentd",
      "Options" :  {
        "fluentd-address" : "foo:24224",
        "tag" : "foobar"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I've not tested with fluentd, but I know this configuration with the awslogs driver works:

```
"ContainerDefinitions": [
  {
    "Name": { "Ref": "ContainerName" },
    "PortMappings": [ ... code omitted ... ],
    "LogConfiguration": {
      "LogDriver": "awslogs",
      "Options": {
        "awslogs-group": { "Ref": "LogGroupName" },
        "awslogs-region": { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": { "Ref": "ContainerName" }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having an issue in Cloud Formation because of the case. This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2022: `LogConfiguration` is supported by `ContainerDefinitions`:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html